# make custom queries using sequelizejs

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelizejs orm in my nodejs app. And I dont have its documentation mentioning how to make custom sql queries. I found an example by googling but couldnt understand its syntax. and what the role of this callee function.

```
  var callee = {
                    build: function(result, config) {
                        console.log("callee", result);
                    }
                };
                sequelize.query("SELECT * from Users", callee).on("success", function(){
                    console.log("success");

                });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to execute custom query and fetch the results of it you can do

```
sequelize.query('sql query', null, { raw: true }).success(function(data){})
```

If you need smth else, please explain what you want to achieve :)

Comment: What do the `null` and `{ raw: true }` fields of the query function represent?

Comment: those things are obsolete with the latest release of sequelize. the second parameter is the model in which the query will result. so if you'd `select * from myModel` you could pass MyModel as second param and the result would be an array of MyModel instances. `raw: true` means that sequelize should not transform the result into instances

Comment: If you use nest with sequelizejs, you can write code like the following.

    async summary(): Promise<object> {
        const [summary] = await this.shopDeviceBillRepository.sequelize.query(
            `select
            count(*) as count, sum(transcnt) as totalTransCnt, sum(dramt) as totalDrAmt, sum(cramt) as totalCrAmt
            from t_shopdevice_bill`,
            { raw: true, plain: false, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
        return summary;
    }